# UItest case running issue in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

Provisioning profile 'example app' has app ID 'com.example.app', which does not match the bundle ID 'com.example.app.xctrunner'."
while running uitest cases i am getting this error i am using xcode 14.3

I have tried several solutions to resolve the issue, including:

Deleted derived data clean the build, deleted the app and relaunched xcode.

Ensuring that the Bundle ID for the XCUITest target is correctly set to end with ".xctrunner."
Updating provisioning profiles and re-signing the target.
Despite implementing these solutions, the issue persists, and I am unable to proceed with my XCUITest automation. The mismatch between the provisioning profile app ID and the XCUITest bundle ID is causing complications.